# How to get Copernicus DEM GeoTIFFs for a bounding box using Python

Tags: python, dem, elevation, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

### Background

According to AWS's [Copernicus Digital Elevation Model](https://registry.opendata.aws/copernicus-dem/) page,

> The Copernicus DEM is a Digital Surface Model (DSM) which represents the surface of the Earth including buildings, infrastructure and vegetation. We provide two instances of Copernicus DEM named GLO-30 Public and GLO-90. [...] Data is provided as Cloud Optimized GeoTIFFs.

---

### Aim

I would like to access these GeoTIFFs, using Python. I would like to be able to specify a bounding box, and get those GeoTIFFs which overlap or intersect with that bounding box.

---

### My attempts

**1) Access AWS directly**

After installing `boto3` (with `pip3 install boto3`), I do, relying on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34866092/8565438) to the question [Can I use boto3 anonymously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865927/can-i-use-boto3-anonymously/34866092#34866092):

```
import boto3
from botocore import UNSIGNED
from botocore.client import Config

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-central-1', config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED))
```

Then I query for list of objects in the bucket, using the second line of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42091396/8565438) to the question [Use boto3 to download from public bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090830/use-boto3-to-download-from-public-bucket):

```
objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket='copernicus-dem-30m')
```

I get a `dict`, with keys:

```
objects.keys()
# outputs: dict_keys(['ResponseMetadata', 'IsTruncated', 'Marker', 'Contents', 'Name', 'Prefix', 'MaxKeys', 'EncodingType'])
```

I access `Contents`, which is a list, so viewing the first element:

```
objects['Contents'][0]
```

I get:

```
{'ETag': '"e0c8b05f7999eedd83ba85e5c94cb670"',
 'Key': 'Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N00_00_E006_00_DEM/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N00_00_E006_00_DEM.tif',
 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 25, 7, 51, 3, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 'Size': 3706379,
 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}
```

Viewing `objects['Contents'][0]['Key']` gives me `Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N00_00_E006_00_DEM/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N00_00_E006_00_DEM.tif`, which is a string. So this didn't got me much closer to accessing the actual TIFF data in a Python notebook.

---

**2) Using opentopography.org**

Googling "search in GLO-30 bucket" lead me to [OpenTopography's search map](https://portal.opentopography.org/raster?opentopoID=OTSDEM.032021.4326.3). After selecting a small region on the map & filling other other details (like email), and waiting a few moments, I get to:

[image]

where I can download a `.tar.gz` file. Upon extraction, I find a `.tif` file.

I believe this is an example of the files I am looking for, but this method does not use Pyhton at all, and it is not suitable for automated processes.

---

### Question

**How do I access the TIF files using Python?**

I am looking for a similar thing to this this:

```
geotiffs = client.search_geotiffs(bounding_box=[59,10,60,11])
```

where the returned `geotiffs` is a list of tiff files from the GLO-30, intersecting or overlapping with the bounding box defined by points 59N10E & 60N11E, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html), here's how you download a file:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME')
```

In your example it might look like this

```
key = objects['Contents'][0]['Key']
s3.download_file('copernicus-dem-30m', key, key.split('/')[-1])
```

As for downloading all overlapping tiles, the numbers in the filename reference the lower left (south west) corner of the tile. The code to generate the filenames will look something like this:

- Generate all northings as an inclusive range between `math.floor(bounding_box_south)` and `math.ceil(bounding_box_north) - 1)`. Do the same for eastings.
- Take every combination of northing and easting, convert into `N00_00_E006_00` format. Copernicus doesn't have fractional tiles, it's all `[N|S]xx_00_[E|W]xxx_00`.
- Format that into an s3 key like the one in your question.
- Download with boto3.

Comment: Very cool. Thanks. If I don't straight want to download, but I'd like to get an URL I can use to download the tiff (by pasting it to my browser, for example), do you know how to modify this script? I guess I should switch the last line to something, I don't see to what yet.

Comment: Posted a question here about the above issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69376206/how-to-generate-url-to-download-file-from-s3-bucket

Answer (score 3):

Try our open source python package available through `PyPI` or `conda-forge` that merges tiles from the open AWS registry of Copernicus 30 meter DEM. (Obviously: I am one of the library developers). We are using this for InSAR processing, so there are few more basic transformations that the library can do, which you can read about on the homepage.

https://github.com/ACCESS-Cloud-Based-InSAR/dem-stitcher

```
bounds = [-119.085, 33.402, -118.984, 35.435]
X, p = stitch_dem(bounds,
                  dem_name='glo_30',
                  dst_ellipsoidal_height=False,
                  dst_area_or_point='Point')
# X is an m x n numpy array
# p is a dictionary (or a rasterio profile) including relevant GIS metadata
```

Hope this helps. Lots of information on the page. Can also utilize other global tiles such as NASADEM.

Related: You could also download one of the zipped `geojsons` from the library [here](https://github.com/ACCESS-Cloud-Based-InSAR/dem-stitcher/tree/dev/dem_stitcher/data), unzip it, load it into QGIS, and then click the URLs for tiles you are interested. That seems like that might be good too. For Copernicus 30 meter tiles, the file name is `glo_30.geojson.zip`.